# Error:'Unsupported context type' while creating a new controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am going to implement MvcMusicStore using ASP.NET MVC3, Linq to Sql class instead of Entity Framework, MS SQL Server 2008 pro instead of express ed.

I got the tutorial from [mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com)

I used Linq to Sql class and the Datacontext is MvcMusicSrotedataContext.  When i try to create a new class using this

[image]

it shows an error in a new window when i click add button Error:'**Unsupported context Type**'

So, could you please help me to solve this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in MVC scaffolding doesn't support Linq to SQL -- you'll have to use Entity Framework instead.  (Or don't use the scaffolding, build your own controller/action logic manually.  Or use a [scaffolding plugin](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) that supports Linq to SQL.)

Answer (score 2):

*I got the same issue with EF. I am using the VS 2012.*

**Background:**

The reason for my case was.. this auto generation process (Scaffolding) seems not recognize the partial class concept.

I used the model first approach and I have used inheritance with the entities.
Ex: entity “B” and “C” is inherited from “A”

So in my generated model class “DataModelContainer” which is inherited from “DbContext”,
There is no definition for “DbSet” and “DbSet”
i.e: the following two lines were not there

```
public DbSet<B> B { get; set; }
public DbSet<C> C { get; set; }
```

Generated “DataModelContainer” class I a partial class, so I completed the other part, using the concept of partial class. And this would be a problem for Scaffolding.

**Solution**

My workaround was, just removed the partial class I added manually. And added the definitions for “DbSet” and “DbSet” in to the auto generated class.
The problem with this solution is, I have to repeat the same thing when I regenerate the model classes.

Comment: I had to remove the partial class and also have it derive directly from DbContext