# Is there a way in asp.net web api / mvc to use a context model coming from a referenced dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I just want to know if it is possible to use a context in asp.net web-api / mvc that was coming from a referenced DLL file. Because what I did here was that I created a separate project library for my models and wanted to used it just by adding it as a referenced to my main project. But when I created a web-api controller, and select that context coming from   the referenced DLL, it gave me an error that the context is not supported.

Is this possible or not? And if it is, can someone help me with the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the entire error description.

Comment: When I created a new Controller for Employee then select my DBContext from a referenced DLL, it will not create the Controller, and a message box will show with a message "Unsupported context type." that's all there's no other.

Comment: Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555910/errorunsupported-context-type-while-creating-a-new-controler

Comment: I have done it before with WPF and a seperate project library so in theory it should work, does it give a more detailed Inner Exception error?  Can you post the code that is referencing it?

Comment: I can confirm that this does work in my own project. I use Entity Framework 5.0 in a Class Library project, and my dbContext can be referenced just fine in my WebAPI project.

Answer (score 0):

As [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192536/eric-falsken) said it will work fine with entity framework, i assume you are not using it try using poco entity install the nuget, it will give you a separate context along with models which you can reference in the other projects as well.

I faced a similar issue, I added `IDisposable` interface to my `DbContext` and it worked. I Also assume that you have added the reference of the dll in the project